# PLC s7-1200 Ladder logic

Tags: plc, siemens

I'm checking some software for PLC s7-1200

According to my knowledge current time will never be > max time. hence, the logic will never trigger [so the code following P_TRIG is useless] ?
**[I'm referring to the yellow highlighted area]**

[image]

**Resources:**
[s7-1200_system_manual](https://support.industry.siemens.com/dl/dl-media/129/109764129/att_974297/v6/s71200_system_manual_html5/en-US/index.html#treeId=legalinfo)
[timer operation](https://support.industry.siemens.com/dl/dl-media/129/109764129/att_974297/v6/s71200_system_manual_html5/en-US/index.html#treeId=e2e672865cf55df56f4bd7d40b1fcf07)

Comment: Your image is an awful mess. Can you repost it and use white to blank out any irrelevant parts instead of scribbling. Please also add a link to the programming manual for the S7-1200.

Comment: @Transistor thanks. edited. i made it black to show that its hidden variable name. i highlighted two variables with colors to say that the matching colors = same variable.

Comment: That's much better.

Comment: As an expert of Simatic programming, I can say that this ladder code is a mess.

Comment: @marko thank you, im not expert i ve mession to understand the program of system that is written by non professional and create document of how this logic work. im my self not plc programmer but i think that this logic will not work?

Comment: I would not spend any further time debugging this, if it does not work OK, then you have to start from scratch.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič it does work but logic such as flowchart should be written by me. but i can see its long rungs (although im not very confident of how program scan order really really works [ie vertical horizontal stuff]) but i can guess 90% correct. thanks for your feedback i will take the answer as no from transistor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. [Timer operation](https://support.industry.siemens.com/dl/dl-media/129/109764129/att_974297/v6/s71200_system_manual_html5/en-US/index.html#treeId=e2e672865cf55df56f4bd7d40b1fcf07) pages shows that ET, elapsed time, stops when the PT, preset, time is reached. From that we can deduce that we will never get ET > PT.*

On the basis of the above information

```
current_Time                 ET
---| > |---        =    ---| > |---
Max_Time                     PT
```

can never be true.

Comment: hi @Transistor, this is what i was referring to in the question. i just wanted to ask here to be 100% sure of this problem. are you sure or assuming just like me.

Comment: Look at the diagram. ET always stops when PT is reached. It does the same on all the timer varieties. My answer is based on reading the manual only. I haven't worked on that PLC.